# Angular 2+ Firebase Authentication - Set Login State Persistence

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I've set up authentication using firebase for an angular app in an auth service, and I'm trying to ensure session state persistence following successful login.

I've seen that firebase is supposed to have state persistence by default, but current logins in the app only last until the page is refreshed, after which login is required again, which doesn't seem right.

I know that I have to use the statePersistence method, as shown in the documentation, but this doesn't make it clear as to how this is actually implemented into a login/auth service in angular 2+ apps.

How to I implement session statePersistence into the following authentication service?:

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

@Injectable()

export class AuthService {

  private user: Observable<firebase.User>;

  isAuthenticated: boolean = false;

  constructor(private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {
    this.user = firebaseAuth.authState;
  }

  signIn(email: string, password: string) {
    this.firebaseAuth
        .auth
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(value => {
            console.log('Signed In');
            this.isAuthenticated = true;
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Sign-In Error: ', err.message);
        });
  }

  signInGoogle() {
    return this.firebaseAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(
        new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
    )
  }
```

Comment: Did you got any solution ?

Answer (score 3):

You're importing the entire `firebase` module. Only import `auth`. The following works for me:

```js
// Don't import the whole module, only `auth`.
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';

constructor(private readonly afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

signIn() {
  this.afAuth.auth.setPersistence(auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL).then(() => {
    // Now sign-in using your chosen method.
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInAnonymously();
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Handle errors here.
    let errorCode = error.code;
    let errorMessage = error.message;
    console.error(errorCode, errorMessage);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add

```
this.firebaseAuth
    .auth

    .setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)

    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

Comment: add some explanation please

Answer (score 0):

It is likely you are not using `onAuthStateChanged` listener to detect the initial Auth state on page load.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    // User signed in.
  } else {
    // User not signed in.
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that hasn't really answered my question. I have no idea where this is supposed to go in the code I've provided above.