# Has firebaseUI no 'keep me signed in' option?

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, firebaseui, google-authentication

Implementing firebaseUI in Angular, I am missing support for a 'keep me signed in' option.

I realize firebaseUI is renewing the flow of 'signing up' and 'logging in', merging those two steps into one (https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/665#issuecomment-596197657). 
However I cannot find an excuse for not offering the user the security option of choosing the right auth persistence (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence). 
firebaseUI-angular partly document a firebaseui.disableAutoSignIn(), but this is not a toggle, but only a one-way option (https://github.com/RaphaelJenni/FirebaseUI-Angular#disable-autosign).

So, what am I missing here? 
How should a user protect his data, if visiting his account on a public device, when auth persistence is implicit set to LOCAL?

UPDATE

After a couple of rounds, I got to a working 'keep me signed in'-option - but only using Google sign-in, not when using Email/Link sign-in.

The core problem with Email/Link is that the emailed link/url authenticates in a new browser tab, and during this it turns auth persistence on hard. The emailed link/url goes to firebaseapp.com that authenticates and re-directs to the Angular app. So how to pass on the user's persistence choice in this flow?

A firebaseUI-web + Angular sandbox is very fast to set up:

1. Blank Angular project
2. npm i firebase @angular/fire firebaseui --save
3. firebaseConfig set in environment.ts
4. Below code

app.module.ts:

```
import {AngularFireModule} from '@angular/fire';
import {AngularFireAuthModule} from '@angular/fire/auth';
import {environment} from 'src/environments/environment';
...
@NgModule({ ...
    imports: [ ...
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
        AngularFireAuthModule,
    ...
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    ui: firebaseui.auth.AuthUI; // firebaseUI reference
    uiLinkUrl = false;
    keepSignin = false;

    constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());

        if (this.ui.isPendingRedirect()) {
            this.uiLinkUrl = true;
        }

        this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((response) => {
            if (response) {
                // update html element if not routing.
                this.showFirebaseUI(); 
            } else {
                // only update persistence if signed out, and not reroute.
                if (!this.uiLinkUrl) {
                    this.afAuth.auth.setPersistence(this.keepSignin ? 
                        firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL : 
                        firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION);
                }
                this.uiLinkUrl = false;
                this.showFirebaseUI();
            }
        });
    }

    toggleKeepSignin() {
        this.keepSignin = !this.keepSignin;
        this.afAuth.auth.setPersistence(this.keepSignin ? 
            firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL : 
            firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION);
    }

    showFirebaseUI() {
        // The start method will wait until the DOM is loaded.
        this.ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', {
            callbacks: {
                uiShown: function () {
                    document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
                },
                signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function (authResult, redirectUrl) {
                    return false;
                },
            },
            credentialHelper: firebaseui.auth.CredentialHelper.NONE,
            signInFlow: 'popup',
            signInOptions: [
                { provider: firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID, 
                    customParameters: {prompt: 'select_account'} },
                { provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID, 
                    signInMethod: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.EMAIL_LINK_SIGN_IN_METHOD },
            ],
        });
    }
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<div *ngIf="afAuth.auth.currentUser">
    <h1 style="color:#0a0;">Signed IN</h1>
    <button (click)="afAuth.auth.signOut()">Sign Out</button>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!afAuth.auth.currentUser">
    <h1 style="color:#a00;">Signed OUT</h1>
</div>

<div style="background:#222;" id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
<div id="loader">Loading...</div>

<div style="text-align:center;" (click)="toggleKeepSignin()">
    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="keepSignin">Keep me signed in
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2+ Firebase Authentication - Set Login State Persistence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48646077/angular-2-firebase-authentication-set-login-state-persistence)

Comment: The above link shows how to set persistence for all components using the Firebase Auth on Angular.  FirebaseUI doesn't need to provide it as a dedicated option when you can set it yourself universally.

Comment: Thanks Doug, for pointing out missing info in my question; I have updated it. I have tried to control persistence outside firebaseUI, but it does not seem to work. I suspect firebaseUI tangles with persistence (since it has the disableAutoSignIn()).

Comment: You should probably then edit your question to show the exact code that doesn't work the way you expect, and what you observed instead.

Comment: Thanks Doug, I have rewritten my question, now that auth.setPersistence() seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Just a follow-up on firebaseUI, on what else to consider before switching.

I ended up waisting 2 weeks trying to switch to firebaseUI-web. FirebaseUI is just not for everyone. I hoped to switch from my existing own code and save on maintenance, but firebaseUI is both too weird and too limited when it comes to offering traditional authentication functionality.

FirebaseUI-web has "automatic account linking", that does not allow you to use both your email and your google account to log in, if they do not share the same emails address. If the email you try to log in with is already associated with a federated provider, firebaseUI actually does not link accounts, but forces user to use the federated login. 
https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/102

FirebasUI-web has no separate sign-up and sign-in for email, which could be smart if switching to email/link instead of email/password. However, the approach confuses many. [https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/665](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/665#issuecomment-596197657) - 
https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/499

FirebasUI-web does not offer requireDisplayName for email/link, only for email/password, so you will end up without  a display name.

FirebaseUI-web email/link by nature sends an authentication link to the user's inbox, and this opens the web app in a new second browser tab, which can be confusing. FirebaseUI-web email/password is not really an option, as you need to handle email confirmation etc. outside FirebaseUI. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60673348](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60673348/how-to-avoid-that-firebaseui-email-link-authentication-opens-a-second-browser-ta)

FirebasUI-web does not offer a way to transfer a firebase user account to another person (e.g. employee leaving firm situation). This would require you to code linking features and email-rename yourself. This was the final deal breaker for me.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the pain. I have same problem with account linking, sometimes it works.. sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: I've spent the same amount of time on integrating firebaseUI and I wish I knew this issue before migrating to Firebase auth.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out how to implement firebaseUI with user controlled persistence ('keep me signed in' option). The solution involves (1) carefull placement of calls to auth.setPersistence(), and (2) passing the user's persistence choice in the email/link URL.
Hope the below description and sample can help others with the same need for optimal authentication safety.

I am still wondering why this is not part of firebaseUI, as managing the scenarios is a bit tricky. In my view remembering authentication as the default is jeopardizing data safety, and the argument of minimizing "user experience friction" is not valid for this default (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence, second paragraph). The persisted authentication of  firebaseUI jeopardize data safety when signing in on public devices, as it requires that users explicitly remember to sign out.

I have setup a Stackblitz app to illustrate FirebaseUI authentication with persistence as a user-option.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ehm3en.

1. To control persistence for federated sign-in like Google,
   persistence is updated if authState is initially signed out.
   Otherwise persistence is not changed, to preserve default.
2. To control persistence for email/link sign-in, the user's choice of
   persistence is passed through the sign-in email as a URL parameter.
   (Proper try out involves opening the app in a new browser tab; to do
   this with Stackblitz, reopen the Stackblitz link).

P.S. Regarding the optional firebaseUI-angular alternative (for angular clients only), I fail to see any reason for using this potentially complicating extra layer, as firebaseUI-web require the same minimal code to implement firebaseUI. In fact, the need for variable configuration of firebaseUI might be more difficult with firebaseUI-angular.
See app.component.ts for further documentation and sandbox instructions.

Comment: I noticed your call to setPersistence() is not awaiting or thenning the returned promise, so you may have a race condition between setting the persistence mode, and the later ui.start() call